# Inner Count of Mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I need to Count the inner records in following mongo document (And also I have to get those count of all the documents),

```
  "_id": ObjectId("503208f5b5db0135387d9249"),
   "function": "getNumberOfRecords",
   "graph": {
       "AB1": {
           "5028cbf7d7262c333a000cb0": 1,
           "5028ede7d7262c333a0011fb": 1
       },
       "AB2": {
           "5028ef9cd7262c333a001219": 1,
           "5028fb9cd7262c333a001c7f": 1,
           "5028fb9cd7262c333a001c80": 1,
           "5028fefcd7262c333a002354": 1,
           "50290d55d7262c333a0024e0": 1,
           "502918c9d7262c333a0025c3": 1,
           "502918c9d7262c333a0025c4": 1,
           "50293220d7262c333a002727": 1,
           "50293220d7262c333a002728": 1,
           "50293220d7262c333a002729": 1,
           "50293220d7262c333a00272a": 1,
           "50295a5bd7262c333a003bbc": 1
       },
       "AB3": {
           "5028ff00d7262c333a002363": 1,
           "50295a5ed7262c333a003bcb": 1
       },
       "AB4": {
           "50293fdfd7262c333a002977": 1
       }
   },
   "nameFilter": "name",
   "siteFilter": "sitename"
}
```

I need the result as,

```
AB1 > 2
AB2 > 12
AB3 > 2
```

like wise.....

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it in mongodb is to create extra count fields and update them though the client code.

So I would suggest following schema changes to feet your need:

```
{
 graphsCount: 1,
 graph: [
       {
          name: "AB1",
          count: 2,
          items: {
             "5028ff00d7262c333a002363": 1,
             "50295a5ed7262c333a003bcb": 1
         }
        }
]
}
```

No you can easy achieve what you need (`AB1 > 2`):

```
db.items.find({"graph.name" : "AB1", {"$gt": {"graph.count": 2}} })
```

Keep in your mind that above query return all **root** documents which have in nested graph array at least one item with name "AB1" and with count > 2.

Comment: Thnaks Andrew. But the problem is I can't change the JSON. I can't put count in to the JSON.

Comment: @ChamithMalinda: Run away from a project where you can't change everything :). Another solution is load documents and query `AB1 > 2` from the client code.

Comment: Have you considered map reduce or the new aggregation framework (available in MongoDB version 2.2, due to be released soon)? Restructuring your data is the best and most performant solution, but if that's not an option,  MR: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce and new aggregation framework: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Comment: @Jenna: I think MR is not an option, because it also very slow. The new aggregation framework seems to be right solution, but I haven't tried it a bit so far. It would be nice if you can show us how it can be accomplished with new aggregation features ;) Thanks!

Comment: Hi guys, very sorry- I was mistaken.  In version 2.2, the new aggregation framework cannot be used to count the number of fields in a document.  If AB1 were an array of embedded documents (rather than a single doc with multiple fields), you could use the $unwind operator in combination with $group and $sum.  This aggregation is possible with map reduce, but as you point out, MR is slow.